# Transparent image - is it possible in JS?

Tags: javascript, image, transparency

Is it possible to set transparency of any image in javascript?
And how can I do that?

Comment: Are you using any javascript library/framework, or just vanilla JS?

Comment: for me JS is raw javascript. So i'm not using any.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If using plain javascript this should work:

```
function SetOpacity( imageid, opacity ) {
    var s= document.getElementById(imageid).style;
    s.opacity = ( opacity / 100 );
    s.MozOpacity = ( opacity / 100 );
    s.KhtmlOpacity = ( opacity / 100 );
    s.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity + ')';
}
```

Call by: `SetOpacity('myImg', 50); //Half transparent`

[Source here](http://www.drquincy.com/blog/cross-browser-javascript-image-opacity-changing-function/)

Comment: Would be more efficient to use a variable for opacity / 100: var decentBrowserOpacityValue = opacity / 100, OR let opacity be a value between 0-1, and use s.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + (opacity*100) + ')';

Comment: @Kooilnc - Possibly, is 1 variable assignment and 1 division cheaper than 3 divisions?  I'm not sure, but I bet it's a infinitesimally small difference either way.  In this case the vast majority of your work is the browser's rendering engine making the image transparent...the difference in variable assignment here is a micro-optimization that arguably makes the code less readable, so I tend to stay away in these simple cases.

Comment: @Nick Craver - it's micro indeed, but you know how it is: many micros tend to make a big one. Another point may be the 'microsoft orientedness' of the function, which I adressed in the OR clause. Well, it's a matter of taste I suppose.

Comment: Is `MozOpacity` necessary? I use `opacity` and not `-moz-opacity` in my CSS all the time for Firefox and it works just fine.

Comment: @Kooilnc - If I wanted optimization and true cross-browser support, I'd use jQuery...which I do :)  Normally I agree with optimizations pay off in the big picture, but not in this case, test for yourself: http://pastie.org/858174 Running this 500,000 times with 1.5 million divisons saves a whole 2 hundredths of a second :)  In this case it's very micro, and not likely to add up to any appreciable benefit...and results in much less readable code.  The 2 seconds it'll save someone trying to figure out what's going on is probably more than the function will ever save in it's lifetime :)

Comment: @fudgey - Just in case you want to support something as old as possible, for practical purposes, yes it could probably be omitted.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$('#yourImageId').css('opacity', .5);
```